# Salesforce to magento

Tags: rest-api, oauth2

I want to  make an Apex class to consume a Magento wsdl Rest api with oAuth 2 (without username and password )?
Please ,how can i do that ?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts.htm

Answer (score 2):

You will need to generate Apex class form the WSDL generated from Magento.

Below is the process:

> - In the Salesforce, from Setup, enter Apex Classes in the Quick Find    box, then select Apex Classes.
> - Click Generate from WSDL.
> - Click Browse to navigate to a WSDL document on your local hard drive or network,    or type in the full path.

This WSDL document is the basis for the Apex class you are creating.

[Reference document: Apex WSDL Generation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex.htm)

**Regarding the Auth 2.0.** 
 
You will need to develop web-user flow in Salesforce and save that session/access-token in custom settings in Salesforce. Those "session" can be utilized to communicate via generated Apex class via WSDL.